# Getting a value from one table to pull up values from another table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, parameters

I am trying to lookup an employeeid from one table based on the windows login name, and use this employeeid to get values from another table to add them up.  So, for Bill, the employeeid is 1 in tblEmployees.  I sum all noofhours in tblTimeAvailable where employeeid equals 1 and display this on my webpage.  It's not working.  I can't figure out how to search the second table by the employeeid found in the first table.  (I'm rewriting code because of sql injection.)

```
Dim windowsLoginName As System.String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name   'System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name

Dim split As String() = Nothing
Dim vname As String
'Get network login name (name only)
split = windowsLoginName.Split("\".ToCharArray)
vname = split(1)
Dim Connection As String = "Data Source=WillSQL\ict2;Initial Catalog=TimeSQL;Integrated Security=SSPI"
Using con As New SqlConnection(Connection)
    Dim sqlemp As String = "SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployees where login = @loginname"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqlemp, con)
    con.Open()
    rve = cmde.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@loginname", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = vname})

End Using
```

When I look at value of rve, it's giving me @loginname and not the employeeid. FYI - there will always be only one row in tblEmployees because each Windows login name is unique.

```
    'Get Sick Time 
    Using con As New SqlConnection(Connection)
       Dim sqls1 As String = "Select SUM(NoofHours) as Total from tblTimeAvailable where workcode = 1 and EmployeeID = @employeeid"
       Dim command As New SqlCommand(sqls1, con)
       con.Open()
       rvsa = cmde.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@employeeid", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Value = rve})
    End Using
   ' If the sum equals 0, show 0 on webpage.  If another value, show value. 
   If IsDBNull(rvsa) Then
       rvsa = 0
       TextBoxsa.Text = 0
   Else
       TextBoxsa.Text = rvsa.ToString
    End If
```

I appreciate any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never executing the command.  After setting the values of the various parameters, you need to then call one of the execute methods on the `SqlCommand` object.  In this case, since you are just reading a single value from a single row, you can simply use the `ExecuteScalar` method:

```
rve = command.ExecuteScalar()
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now I get it!